# How to get column names and other metadata from a table or resultset

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ado.net

EX In "Data" table

- type of column from moisture to end is Boolean
- I want to get column name has data is "1" to combobox

Specifically, for each row of my result set, I need a collection of those column names which contain the value `1` so I can populate a combobox.

Sorry for my English I'm not good enough.

[pic "Data" table](http://upic.me/i/cu/6css1.png)

Comment: I believe you are asking how, in C# / .net, to write a program that retrieves information about column names and column data types from a MySQL result set. Is that correct?  At any rate, phpmyadmin has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, do you want to read specific data from mysql using c# and load it to combobox?

Comment: yes i do I want to get column name has data is "1" to combobox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using  the MySQL .net connector (and any RDMS connector) when you are reading a result set from a query, you will have a DataReader object. In MySQL's case it is a MySqlDataReader.

For example (from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html)

```
       string sql = "SELECT * FROM data";
       MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
       MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

       while (rdr.Read())
       {
            /* iterate once per row */
            Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]+" -- "+rdr[1]); /* or whatever */
       }
       rdr.Close();
```

Once you have a valid DataReader, you can use the `GetSchemaTable()` method to obtain a `DataTable` collection of data describing the result set. This information comes from MySQL as part of the result set.  For example:

```
       MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
       DataTable schema = rdr.GetSchemaTable();
```

This `DataTable` contains a row for each column in the result set.   You can access useful information about your columns in your result set like this:

```
        foreach (DataRow rdrColumn in schema.Rows) {
            String columnName = rdrColumn[schema.Columns["ColumnName"]].ToString();
            String dataType = rdrColumn[schema.Columns["DataType"]].ToString();    
        }
```

There are also items named `ColumnSize`, `NumericPrecision`, `NumericScale`, and so forth. Each of these is available for each column in the result set if you need them.

**Edit**
You can make a Dictionary holding the names of the result set's columns like this:

```
        Dictionary<int,String> columnNames = new Dictionary<int,string>();
        int index = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows) {
            columnNames.Add(index,row[schema.Columns["ColumnName"]].ToString());
            index++;
        }
```

Thereafter, as you iterate through the rows, you can create a List of columns, by name, with a certain row value.

```
        while (rdr.Read()) {
            /* for each row */
            List<String> listOfColumns = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++) {
                var val = rdr[i];
                if ("1" == val) {
                    /* if the value of the column is 1, add the column name from the dictionary */
                    listOfColumns.Add(columnNames[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

For examples of looking at result set metadata see here.  https://etutorials.org/Programming/ado+net/Part+I+ADO.NET+Tutorial/Chapter+5.+DataReaders/5.4+DataReaders+and+Schema+Information/

Comment: yes i can get column name thank .but How to get column name has data is"1"

Answer (score 1):

this query will help you  `DESCRIBE my_table;`

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
```

refer the clink for more clarification: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-columns.html